# React useEffect hook with long running task and merge state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

I have a scenario where a user can upload files using drag and drop.

I use an effect with an empty depedency array to setup an RXJS subscription which handles the dropped files and upload time:

```
const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    ...
    fileUploadSubject.subscribe(newAttachments => {
       setAttachments([...attachments,newAttachments])
    })
    ...
    return () => {
      subscriptions.forEach(s => {
        s.unsubscribe()
      })
    }
},[])
```

Problem is that the effect has dependencies on `attachments` as well as `setAttachments` function.

If I add `attachments` to the dependency array I will unsubscribe to the existing uploads. Also `attachment` state is not updated inside the effect due to its closure.

How do I tackle a scenario like this? I have thought of multiple ways but can't seem to find a simple way forward.

Comment: where `fileUploadSubject` is coming from? is it also created inside your component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setState functions of `useState` support a [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form:

```
const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    ...
    const subscription = fileUploadSubject.subscribe(newAttachments => {
       setAttachments((oldAttachments) => [...oldAttachments, newAttachments])
    })
    ...
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
}, [setAttachments, fileUploadSubject])
```

Functions that never change (i.e. both here) can be omitted in the dependency list, but I prefer to list them to prevent forgetting some dependency. There are [eslint rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) for that tough.

Answer (score 2):

> If I add attachments to the dependency array I will unsubscribe to the existing uploads

Not sure why its unsubscribing, not familiar with `fileUploadSubject.subscribe`

> Also attachment state is not updated inside the effect due to its closure

You can [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of `useState`, this way you don't need to depend on the state in your effect.
Maybe something like this:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_ATTACH":
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function App() {
  const [attachments, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
    fileUploadSubject.subscribe(newAttachments => {
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_ATTACH", payload: newAttachments });
    });
    // ...
    return () => {
      subscriptions.forEach(s => {
        s.unsubscribe();
      });
    };
  }, [/*fileUploadSubject?,  subscriptions? */]);

  return <div>{ /* some UI */ }</div>;
}
```

I still think it's odd that your effect doesn't depend on anything, make sure `subscriptions` and `fileUploadSubject` really shouldn't be inside the dependencies array.